# filelist() can't perform in a for loop

Tags: r

I'm trying to read some files like "SN1_a_1,csv", "SN2_a_1,csv", "SN3_a_1.csv","SN1_a_2.csv","SN2_a_2.csv","SN3_a_2.csv", in two for loops.

Then I got an

> Error: In file(file, "rt"):cannot open file
>   '/Users/young/Desktop/1/NA': No such file or directory

When j<-1, the loop works fine. But when j<-2, then filelist1 returned as an empty list.
I tried to manually run

```
filelist1<-list.files(path=folder, pattern = paste0(".*a_",j,".csv"))
```

in console window after I got the Error, and it worked.
Can anyone solve my problem, it's just so wired.

```
folder<- "/Users/young/Desktop/1/"
for(j in 1:2) {
  filelist1 <- list.files(path = folder, pattern = paste0(".*a_", j, ".csv")) 
  for (h in 1:length(filelist1)){
    a1 <- read.csv(paste0(folder, filelist1[h]), header = TRUE)
  }
}
```

Comment: Instead of `1:length(filelist1)` use `seq_along(filelist1)`. This is because `length(filelist1)` can be zero. See what gives `1:0`. And please learn how to format code.

Comment: Thank you for your advice! But the problem is "filelist1" is empty in the second round of for(j in 1:2). To be more specific, when j<-2, the "filelist1" then returned as empty. The for (h in 1:length(filelist1)) actually is fine.

Comment: Are you sure that `"*a_2.csv"` files are in the same directory? Is the most obvious explanation to `list.files()` returning an empty array. I ask because I see an "1" at the end of your `folder` string, Maybe files with "2.csv" are in folder named "2", but you never change the 1 in the `folder` string.

Comment: @PuyangGeng That is exactly what I say. If `filelist1` is empty then its length is zero and the read csv function throws that error. Use `seq_along` and see for yourself.